# Stafflynx application for Silverlight? Sample code to download?

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight

I found Stafflynx WPF application just amazing:

http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=115

Anyone knows if is applicable for Silverlight?

Where can I download it? (sample code)

Thanks!

Rodrigo

Answer (score 0):

I think I remember Billy Hollis saying that he was thinking of porting it to Silverlight. This is an application that his team was building for a specific client, not for distribution.

I don't know of anywhere you can download it.

It is a very impressive application.